# Design flat url in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a list view in which I have a url in which by clicking on it, it directs me to detail view. I want this url to be a flat urls in this manner `127.0.0.1:8000/?id=4` and id is the id of the object how could I do that? I wondered I could do by having a `serializer.SerializerMethodField` and implement a `get_url` function. Is there a better approach?

**EDIT**
Now I have url in this manner `127.0.0.1:8000/4/` and this is my serializer

```py
#serizlier.py
class SampleSerizlier(serizlier.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name="app-name:view-name", lookup_field='id'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = "__all__"
```

the `HyperlinkIdentityField` generates urls in this way `127.0.0.1:8000/4/` but I want to generate urls in the way I mentioned above. And I wondered to do that by `SerializerMethodField` and defining a `get_url` and do everything manualy. Is there a better way? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is a "flat URL"? Why don't you want the URL to be just `127.0.0.1:8000/4` for example? And where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: As I know flat urls are urls in this manner ```127.0.0.1/id=4``` and nested urls are the manner you have typed. At first I have designed my url in nested manner but when I read the DRF docs and I saw the last line of [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example_2) in doc. I decided to change my design but I don't know how to change it. @DanielRoseman

Comment: @eng.mrgh: there is nothing really nested about it. A `/` can be seen as a directory, but in fact that is only how humans see this.

Answer (score 0):

I Think 
in your model

```
class Modelname(models.Model):
    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('app_name:url_name', args=(self.pk,))
```

In serializer:

```
class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Resource
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_id(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')

        return request.build_absolute_uri(obj.get_url())
```

Add url will be

```
from django.urls import path

    app_name = 'app_name'
    urlpatterns = [

        path('url_name/', your_view.as_view(), name="url_name"),
    ]
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but that is not working for thing I wanted. It show the url in nested API manner but I want to be in flat API manner.

Answer (score -1):

Your view that takes in 127.0.0.1:8000/, before '?id=4' can receive the 'id' through the request data.

Within your view, retrieve the ID with:

```
id = request.GET["id"]
```

If an ID is found, you can then show the detail of the retrieved object, else show the default page.

Comment: @DanielRoseman While it's not the ideal way of doing things, if he wants '?id=4' in the URL, and there is already a view for 127.0.0.1:8000/, then this is definitely a way of doing what he wants.

Comment: No it isn't. Items after `?` are not part of the URL pattern and are received in `request.GET`.

Comment: Ah, I had that as my second solution, but didn't realize that the first one wouldn't work at all. I've deleted the first part of my answer and just stuck with the second. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my mean I meant at nested APIs we use HyperLinkIdentity field so that we have a url (in this form ```127.0.0.1:8000/4/```) in our serializer which directs us to the detail view. My question is how we can have same method for flat APIs  and change the above url to ```127.0.0.1:8000/?id=4``` manner? @PriyamMohanty

Comment: @eng.mrgh Basically, the view that takes in 127.0.0.1:8000/ should check if there exists a request.GET["id"] value. If this value is not None, then the view should display the detail view, and if not, the regular view should be shown. Basically, the ?id=4 can be received in your view's get(self, request, ...) method by request.GET["id"]. What does your view look like? Maybe that can help me clarify for you.